# Dynamodb ConditionalCheckFailedException attribute_not_exists or last_status_modify_time < :val

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, conditional-operator

We use this code to operate dynamodb:

- If `user_id` does not exist, code will insert a record to dynamodb
- if `user_id` does exist and `modify_time` field (in the item) < `last_status_modify_time` (in my code), it will update this item's `modify_time`.

Most times it is success,but sometimes it will throws exception `The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException`. Just want to know is there something wrong with my conditional expression?
This is our code

```
private static void saveRoomStatusToDynamoDB(CacheClient client, ZRRoomItem item) {
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        logger.debug("begin saveRoomStatusToDynamoDB, item: {}", item);
        String condition = String.format(
          "attribute_not_exists(%s) or %s < :val",
          DynamoConstants.FIELD_ZR_ROOM_ITEM_USER_ID,
          DynamoConstants.FIELD_ZR_ROOM_ITEM_LAST_STATUS_MODIFY_TIME);
        Map<String, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
        valueMap.put(":val", item.getLastStatusModifyTime());

        //l_putItem will call dynamodb api
        boolean result = DynamoDBUtil.getInstance().l_putItem(
            DynamoConstants.TABLE_ZR_ROOM_ITEM, item.toDynamoItem(), 
            condition, valueMap);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("saveRoomStatusToDynamoDB error, item: {}, {}",
          item, 
          WebLogger.printStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to perform an `putItem()` with a condition, and the condition evaluates to false, then the update is not carried out and an exception (`ConditionalCheckFailedException`) is thrown.

Based on your question I believe that you expected that when the condition evaluates to false the `putItem()` call just returns normally. In reality it does not: it throws the exception you are getting. Thus, you just need to catch the exception and return from your method.

Further details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html

Comment: I mean sometimes my code throw ConditionalCheckFailedException, but data still can save or update to db. It is very strange. In the theory, if have exception, putItem() will not save data do db. So I want to know whether my condition expression is wrong.

Comment: @AnhuaZhao - how do you that the data can be saved? can you post an example for such a situation (data in the DB, data you want to update)?