# DynamoDB conditional Update throws Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am performing a dynamodb conditional update

```
    def update_item(self, key, refresh_start):
        try:
            update_expression = 'SET refresh_start_time = :refresh_time'
            condition_expression = 'attribute_not_exists(refresh_start_time)' \
                                   'OR :refresh_time >= refresh_start_time'
            expression_attribute_values = {
                ':refresh_time': {'N': str(refresh_start)}
            }

            response = self.dynamo_client.update_item(
                TableName=self.table,
                Key={'id': {'S': key}},
                ConditionExpression=condition_expression,
                UpdateExpression=update_expression,
                ExpressionAttributeValues=expression_attribute_values
            )
            return response
        except ClientError as ce:
            log.error(
                str(LogMessage.create_message(EventType.ERROR.value, DlLogs.DYNAMO_UPDATE_ERROR.value).add_item("Ërror",
                                                                                                              ce)))
   raise ce
```

The refresh_start argument is numeric and the refresh_start_time is also a number type in dynamodb but I get
**[ERROR] ConditionalCheckFailedException: An error occurred (ConditionalCheckFailedException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The conditional request failed**.
Just to summarize I am comparing a local variable value against the refresh_start_time attribute value for the key.
Can somebody please help and let me know where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: `ConditionalCheckFailedException` doesn't mean there was an error in the request - it just means that the condition was false, i.e., maybe the refresh_start_time attribute of the item didn't exist, or maybe it was > your refresh_start. Do you believe it should have been true in your case? Can you give an example?

Comment: It seems your condition failed and hence update did not take place. Now, you might not be expecting an exception, but SDK throws it. Read this answer carefully - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852227/1273882.